# Limit and convergence of a sequence

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, convergence-divergence

I have an exercise of sequences, I figured out half the solution but I'm stuck now, so please help.
This the question I can't figure out how to solve :

Let $a$ a positive real number that is strictly positive, and $\big(x_n\big)$ a sequence defined by :

$x_0=a$ and $\forall n\in \mathbb{N}, x_{n+1}=\frac{x_n}{1+(n+1)x_n^2}$

I proved that if $a=1$ then : $\big(\forall n\in\mathbb{N}^*\big)\ x_n=\frac{1}{n+1}$
Then I proved that if $a>1$ the $\big(x_n\big)$ is decreasing, bounded by $0$ and convergente,
but I couldn't find it's limit. I tried to turn $\frac{x_n}{1+(n+1)x_n^2}$ into a function,
so I wrote it this way : $f_n\big(x\big)=\frac{x}{1+(n+1)x^2}\, \forall x\in\mathbb{R^+}$, because I wanted to use the **Intermediate value theorem**
I proved that $f_n$ is injective and that $f_n\big(\big[0,+\infty\big[\big)=\big[0,+\infty\big[$, so I wanted to prove that $\exists!x_n\in\mathbb{R}_+^*/f_n\big(x_n\big)=\lambda$ when $\lambda$ is a number that exists in $\mathbb{R}_+^*$ that will help me to fin the limit, but I don't know how to choose that number.
I chose $1$ so it gives me :
$\frac{x_n}{1+(n+1)x_n^2}=1\quad\Rightarrow\quad x_n-\big(n+1\big)x_n^2=1$
$\Rightarrow\quad l-\lim\limits_{}(n+1)x_n^2=1$ where $l=\lim\limits_{}x_n$
but I can't solve this limit $\lim\limits_{}(n+1)x_n^2$.

**Please help!**

Comment: Hem, if $x_0=a=1$, then $x_1=\frac1{n+2}$.

Comment: Yes, true. What about it?

Comment: So let me doubt that you proved $x_n=\frac1{n+1}$.

Comment: This is verified for $a=1 $. And then what?

Answer (score 3):

I think it's not necessary to use that Intermediate value theorem. Here is my proof:

First, we use mathematical induction to prove that $(x_n)$ is a monotonic decreasing sequence, and since $x_n>x_{n+1}=\dfrac{x_n}{1+(n+1)x_n^2}$, we obtain that $x_n>0$. So it must converge to some number. One might suspect $lim(x_n)=0$.

Change the equation: $x_{n+1} = \dfrac{x_n}{1+(n+1)x_n^2}$

we obtain: $x_{n+1}+(n+1)x_{n+1}x_n^2=x_n$

divide this by $(n+1)$: $\dfrac{x_{n+1}}{n+1}+x_{n+1}x_n^2=\dfrac{x_n}{n+1}$

Apply the fact that: $x = lim_n x_{n+1}$

$x^3=0\implies x=0$ as $n\to\infty$

So, $lim (x_n) = 0$

The proof written by Murphy is by contradition, my proof is really different from his, hope this gives you some ideas. I think your method may work but it's just very complicated.

Comment: I think your proof is good, but I want to prove it by the Intermediate Value Theorem. But thanks anyway, I like your proof.

Comment: By the way, does $\lim x_n=\lim x_{n+1}$?

Comment: @Anonymous $x_{n+1}$ is also a term in $(x_n)$, therefore if we prove that $(x_n)$ converges then all terms in the sequence should get close to that limit.

Comment: When you take limit at the end you can't have $(n+1) $ in the expression rather you directly get $x=0$. Your proof has thus as error. The right approach is in the answer by Kabo Murphy.

Comment: Looks fine and +1

Comment: @Paramanand Singh OK. thx.

Answer (score 3):

1) $0 <x_n$, $x_{n+1} <x_n$ , strictly decreasing.

Limit $L\ge 0$ exists.

Note :

$L<x_n$ , for all $n$.

2) $0\lt x_{n+1}< \dfrac{a}{1+(n+1)L^2}; $

Assume $L>0$, and take the limit.

Hence?

Comment: You have a typo (now fixed by me). In the denominator you should $(n+1)L^2$ instead of $(n+1)L$.

Comment: Paramand.Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2):

If $\lim x_n>0$ then $\frac {x_n}{1+(n+1)x_n^{2}} \to 0$ since the numerator has a finite limit and the denominator tends to $\infty$.  So we get a contradiction. Hence the limit is necessarily $0$.